# Question opinion-based?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56984821/7069126) and soon it was closed as primarily opinion-based. I edited it to make it clear what I am looking for, which is not an opinion but just an explanation whether or not it would be wrong/dangerous to do it in a way that seems better to me than the flask tutorial. The question got an upvote, as well, so apparently someone else is interested in getting an answer, too.

None of the closers ever came back to me and I still have no help regarding this question. What should I do?

Comment: The title of your question is "Flask with pytest - which application to use?" - people may believe that the question *which application to use* is *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: OK thx for the helpful comment, I'll edit it. Do you know why none of the closers/downvoters pointed this out?

Comment: I don't know. I myself can't even vote to close.

Comment: @TobiasFeil because they do not need to. The question is opinion based, you disagreeing with that does not change the fact that people judge it to be opinion based. You write the question as if asking for advice, that is not what Stack Overflow is for. Using phrasing such as "Is it advisable to just always use client.application?" -> asking for opinions/advice/guidance/mentoring/however you want to call it.

Comment: (so don't phrase questions like that, stick to facts and ask one question)

Comment: OK thx. That's a valuable piece of information. I just don't know why no one else pointed this out... Then I wouldn't have had to open this question, could have corrected it quickly, 4 people wouldn't have had to vote for closing, done...

Comment: @TobiasFeil: I would restructure the questiont to ask "What is the difference between `client.application` and `flaskr.app`".

Comment: @TobiasFeil Some users stopped pointing things out because many OPs don't listen and react to advice, or they would begin to argue when they should update their question instead.

Comment: "which is not an opinion but just an explanation whether or not it would be wrong/dangerous to do it in a way that seems better to me than the flask tutorial" But that *is* an opinion.  Whether it's a good idea to do something is not a fact.  It's an opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether it wouldn't be better to use `client.application` here instead of `flaskr.app`. Or does it not make a difference?

You ask about the specific use of two methods(maybe, not sure) which can do the same task. Users may have different opinion on what the use of each of them will have any difference or not. Also Stack Overflow is not for asking advice on the topics(as stated by @Gimby)

That's why it is an opinion based question.

Comment: "Users may have different opinion on what the use of each of them will have any difference or not" You think so? I was just hoping someone who is experienced with the testing framework would know whether they both internally call the same object or one of them creates a new object. I think that question is clearly answerable without an opinion. But maybe I just didn't word it rightly.

Comment: Ya, maybe the problem is with wording as I saw but the questions like this seem opinion based to me. A user asks *is this correct or this?* Or *Should I use this or that?* Always seem like asking for suggestions and might cause conflict b/w people about the products/methods or as the case may be

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I'll try not to ask like that in the future